# Why is a vehicle's empty weight called its "curb weight"?

Tags: etymology

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curb%20weight) defines *curb weight* as:

> the weight of an automobile with standard equipment and fuel, oil, and coolant

Why is this weight called a vehicle's **curb** weight?

Comment: This is given in the sense of "parked at the curb" (i.e., with no passengers or luggage, etc.). See [curb weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curb_weight).

Comment: It's a bit like the _street value_ of drugs :)

Comment: I agree with Robusto. _Dry weight_, _unladen weight_ and _tare weight_ are used too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Definition and etymology

*Curb weight* (US) or *kerb weight* (UK) is the weight of a car parked at the kerb with standard equipment, oil, water, coolant, petrol but without passengers or goods. Some definitions say a full tank of petrol, but some just say some petrol. It comes from the idea of a car parked by the kerb and ready to go, but waiting for passengers and extra luggage.

The earliest example in the OED is of the UK spelling in 1958, but [*Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=TAnheeIPcAEC&pg=PA306&dq=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22%20etymology&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MabtUPj6Damq4AST9IHgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22%20etymology&f=false) (2004) dates the US spelling to 1949 but I found examples in the early 1930s (and possibly in the late 1920s).

### 1920s

This is a snippet of *[Society of Automotive Engineers Transactions](http://books.google.fi/books?id=0fw1AQAAIAAJ&q=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22&dq=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oqjtUJBEqsvgBOP5gKAH&redir_esc=y)* (1929), so the date could be wrong (but it [looks ok](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=oqjtUJBEqsvgBOP5gKAH&id=0fw1AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22&q=1929#search_anchor)). It contrasts "Curb weight, sedan" with a heavier "Weight, with driver and observer":

[image: Curb weight, sedan 3300 lb.]

### 1930s

Ignoring snippets, the first verifiable examples are from almost identical adverts in the April 1933 editions of *[Popular Science](http://books.google.fi/books?id=_icDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mKftUPz3JuTf4QTP4YGgBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22curb%20weight%22&f=false)* and [*Popular Mechanics*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=E-IDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA496&dq=%22curb%20weight%22%20OR%20%22kerb%20weight%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zaftUIC1F4fK4AT44YC4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22curb%20weight%22%20&f=false):

[image: The Pontiac Economy Straight Eight has a wheelbase of 1 1 5 inches; the curb weight (4-door Sedan) is 3265 pounds.][image: Pontiac's 115' wheelbase and 4-door Sedan curb weight of 3265 pounds assure real big car riding comfort.]

Answer (score 5):

It's the weight of the vehicle, parked at the side of the road (at the *curb*), ready to go, but without any passengers or cargo.

Comment: I'm curious how the car got **to** the curb without fuel, oil, and coolant.  :)

Comment: Curb weight includes those things. Compare "dry weight".

Comment: @AlexFeinman Hah! You're right - I read the definition wrong.  Then this does make sense.